# How to create an array of images as links?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of images

```
images:[
{image: 'img/img01.jpg'},
{image: 'img/img02.jpg'},
]
```

I want to make them as links:

```
images:[
{<a href="#"><img src="img/img01.jpg"/></a>},
{<a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"/></a>},
]
```

And got a syntax error. What is the correct way, pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use strings in your array, like this:

```
images = [
'<a href="#"><img src="img/img01.jpg"/></a>',
'<a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"/></a>'
];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++)
images[i].image='<a href="#"><img src="'+images[i].image+'"/></a>';
```

Will convert your array to

```
{images:[
{image:'<a href="#"><img src="img/img01.jpg"/></a>'},
{image:'<a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"/></a>'},
]}
```

From
`{images:[
{image: 'img/img01.jpg'},
{image: 'img/img02.jpg'},
]}`

Answer (score 1):

```
var images = [{image: '<a href="#"><img src="img/img01.jpg"/></a>'},
              {image: '<a href="#"><img src="img/img02.jpg"/></a>'}
             ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use native method **forEach**. ;)

```
​images.forEach(function(item){
    item.image = '<a href="#"><img src="'+item.image+'"/></a>';
});​
```

Preview - http://jsfiddle.net/NJ6Ck/